# :after and :before elements are invisible under transparent border

Tags: css

I'm tryng to animate :after anf :before elements which intended to be positioned under div border. Snippet below demonstrates working case, but if I uncomment `border: 2px solid transparent;`, pseudo-elements become invisible. 
I tried to change box-sizing - no matter.

The question is: Why transparent border behaves as opaque?

```css
.ex {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgreen;
/*    border: 2px solid transparent; */
    margin: 30px;
}
.ex::after, .ex::before {
    content: " ";
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: red;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.ex::before {
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
}
.ex::after {
    bottom: -2px;
    right: -2px;
}
.ex:hover::after, .ex:hover::before {
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);

}
```

```html
<div class="ex">hover me</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is it happening?**

Actually the area below transparent border is painted with `background-color` by the browser.

**How to fix?:**

Use `background-clip` css property to explicitly tell the browser to paint only the content area of the element (excluding borders) when `background-color` property is applied to the element.

```
.ex {
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) about `background-clip`:

**Demo:**

```css
.ex {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  margin: 30px;
}
.ex::after, .ex::before {
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: red;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.ex::before {
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}
.ex::after {
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
}
.ex:hover::after, .ex:hover::before {
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);

}
```

```html
<div class="ex">hover me</div>
```